# Proper permissions for website directories and to enable rsync deployment

Tags: permissions, webserver, rsync

I'm setting up a new website on a new Ubuntu droplet at Digital Ocean. I set this up previously on a different droplet and rsynced the website contents to it. I followed directions I found on the web, but didn't keep detailed-enough notes. I'm just trying to replicate this on the new Droplet. But I've messed up somehow. My knowledge of permissions, etc. is rudimentary  :-(

---

My server has:  /var/www/html

This is what I did:

•  sudo usermod -a -G www-data [myusername]
•  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
•  sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
•  sudo chmod -R g+rws /var/www

I then created  “/var/www/howardmann.us/public_html” for my website.

(I didn't put the public_html directory in var/www/html. I didn't on my other Droplet. Perhaps I should.)

---

sudo ls -la /var/www

total 16
drwxrwsr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 25 15:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Feb 24 14:27 ..
drwxr-sr-x  3 root     www-data 4096 Feb 25 15:43 howardmann.us
drwxrwsr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 25 15:42 html

---

sudo ls -la /var/www/howardmann.us/public_html
total 8
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Feb 25 15:43 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 root www-data 4096 Feb 25 15:43 ..

---

Now, excerpts of rsync script (successful to my other Droplet) result from my laptop now:

1.

howardm$ ./deploy.sh
sending incremental file list
rsync: failed to set times on "/var/www/howardmann.us/public_html/.": Operation not permitted (1)

2. rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/var/www/howardmann.us/public_html/css" failed: Permission denied (13)
   *** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***

3.

rsync: mkstemp "/var/www/howardmann.us/public_html/.DS_Store.8zaaQg" failed: Permission denied (13)

---

Question: How do I fix ownership and permissions on the server directories for 1) proper permissions for a website and 2) permit a rsync deploy?

For comparison, here is the status of my current working web site on the other Droplet:

---

howardm@howardmann:~$ ls -la /var/www/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 howardm www-data 4096 Mar  5  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root    root     4096 Mar 28  2015 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 howardm www-data 4096 Jun  8  2016 howardmann.us
drwxrwxr-x  2 howardm www-data 4096 Mar 29  2015 html

---

Thanks!

Howard

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed this after reading some more about permissions for a website.

My website folder is titled howardmann.us, which contains a public_html folder with the website contents.

So: /var/www/howardmann.us/public_html. (/var/www also contains a html directory)

I achieved the relevant ownership/permissions with:

1. sudo chown -R howardm:www-data /var/www/

I'm the owner, and www-data the group.

2. sudo usermod -a -G www-data [myusersername]

I'm a member of the www-data group

3. sudo chmod -R 2775 /var/www/

This yields the proper permissions, I believe for a web site.

I made sure the same owner:group applied to all these directories:

---

ls -l /var/www
total 8
drwxr-sr-x 3 howardm www-data 4096 Feb 26 19:23 howardmann.us
drwxrwsr-x 2 howardm www-data 4096 Feb 25 15:42 html

---

ls -l /var/www/howardmann.us
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 11 howardm www-data 4096 Feb  5  2017 public_html

---

Now rsync works without errors.

If anyone believes these ownership/permissions for a website are (substantially) improper, please comment.

Howard